ngx-cleave-directive navigator not defined for angular 17
I imported ngx-cleave-directive from the official documentation here here for my Angular 17 project, and the installation seems to work well until I actually use it in my code as shown below:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule,CommonModule,
    NgxCleaveDirectiveModule],
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrl: './card.component.css'
})

And this is the HTML template:
<input inputmode="numeric"  placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000"   
    id="cardNumber" name="cardNumber" [(ngModel)]="card.cardNumber"  #cardNumber="ngModel"
    [cleave]="{creditCard: true}">
   

I imported it in my code like that, but every time I try to use it in the HTML template, I get this error message:

ERROR ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
at Object.isAndroid (/Users/paolofernandofloresrivera/Documents/paymentForm/paymentForm/node_modules/cleave.js/dist/cleave-esm.js:948:9)
at Cleave.init (/Users/paolofernandofloresrivera/Documents/paymentForm/paymentForm/node_modules/cleave.js/dist/cleave-esm.js:1114:39)
at Cleave (/Users/paolofernandofloresrivera/Documents/paymentForm/paymentForm/node_modules/cleave.js/dist/cleave-esm.js:1098:11)
at NgxCleaveDirective.setCleave (/Users/paolofernandofloresrivera/Documents/paymentForm/paymentForm/node_modules/ngx-cleave-directive/fesm2020/ngx-cleave-directive.mjs:40:27)
at NgxCleaveDirective.set cleave (/Users/paolofernandofloresrivera/Documents/paymentForm/paymentForm/node_modules/ngx-cleave-directive/fesm2020/ngx-cleave-directive.mjs:17:10)
at applyValueToInputField (/Users/paolofernandofloresrivera/Documents/paymentForm/paymentForm/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4035:29)
at writeToDirectiveInput (/Users/paolofernandofloresrivera/Documents/paymentForm/paymentForm/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11096:13)
at setInputsForProperty (/Users/paolofernandofloresrivera/Documents/paymentForm/paymentForm/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12391:9)
at elementPropertyInternal (/Users/paolofernandofloresrivera/Documents/paymentForm/paymentForm/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11692:9)
at Module.ɵɵproperty (/Users/paolofernandofloresrivera/Documents/paymentForm/paymentForm/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:21258:9)

Additionally, if I remove [cleave]="{creditCard: true}" from the input code, it doesn't show the error message, but the cleave import doesn't work (obviously because it's not being used). I already tried solutions from Stack OverFlow, but they don't seem to work or be related. If they are, how could they be?
